# Fastest way to write to a pipe

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fifo

I wrote this program, where in one part, a thread takes char* buffers and write them to a pipe
that was created as follows:

```
 ret_val = mkfifo(lpipename.c_str(), 0666);
 pipehandler = open(lpipename.c_str(), O_RDWR);
```

then I write to the pipe one buffer after another as follows:

```
 int size = string(pcstr->buff).length()
 numWritten = write(pipehandler, pcstr->buff, size);
```

each pcstr->buff is a pointer to a malloc'ed size of a pre-configured size of 1-5 MB

however, it takes too long to write to the pipe , than it does to fill the pcstr->buff (from another source) and it for makes my program run too slow.

Does anyone have any idea of a faster writing method?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason for not knowing the size of `pcstr->buff` (and thus creating a string just to count that)?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes...the size is received from a configuration file

Comment: But are you talking about the third argument?

Comment: Why not save that size instead of computing it again and again?

Comment: `Write()` may be blocking because your data is too big for the kernel's pipe buffer, so it has to wait for the reading process to drain it. You may need to set the stream to non-blocking mode, and buffer the data so you can write it when space is available.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes  I did that...it is now fixed and appeared as follows

Comment: I do not have a problem with the write() being blocking.If I understand correctly, it doesn't have anything to do with the speed in which it writes to the buffer, right?

Comment: If you try to write more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes, your app will block until some other process reads from the pipe, and if you have more writers you may get interleaved writes.

Comment: Pipes work quite fast in practice, but the recieving process has to read and process their data....  Otherwise your writing process may be blocked...

Comment: @ BASILE!!! Thanks man you solved my problem I'm thrilled, I made sure that the process that read(SIZE)s, does that with a SIZE that is equal to the SIZE on write(SIZE). Also. one has to make sure that one doesn't write more than 1MB :-) THANKS GUYS

Comment: No, you don't need to `read(2)` the pipes in chunks of the same size you have `write(2)`-n them on the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> each pcstr->buff is a pointer to a malloc'ed size of a pre-configured size of 1-5 MB

Just save the length somewhere. Copying it into `std::string` just to find out its size is rather wasteful. Or use `strlen()`.

> however, it takes to long to write to the pipe , than it does to fill the pcstr->buff (from another source) and it for makes my program run too slow.

[In Linux the default maximum pipe buffer size is 1Mb as of today](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/fs/pipe.c#L28). You mentioned you write more than 1Mb into the pipe. When that happens the writing thread blocks till some data from the pipe have been consumed.

> Does anyone have any idea of a faster writing method?

Use a plain file in `/dev/shm` or `/tmp`. On latest Linux'es `/tmp` is an in-memory filesystem. This only works though, if the amount of data sent through the pipe can be saved in a file without overflowing the amount of free disk space or memory.

Comment: I didn't quite get the first part about the length...I do have the length in advance...which is what I assigned as a param to the malloc :-) so it was fixed...I will check the second part about the max file size though..sounds interesting. Thanks :-)

Comment: @user1432779: `string(pcstr->buff).length()` - this copies the buffer, returns the string length and then destroys the copy. Do `strlen(pcstr->buff)` instead.

Comment: at the first place I knew what the size is as I invoked
pcstr->buff = malloc(THE SIZE) :-) so I'm now using THE SIZE instead of strlen or length()..thanks though.. I changed THE SIZE to 1MB but it still doesn't write to the buffer as fast as I had expected :-(

Comment: @user1432779: On older Linux kernels the pipe buffer size was 64Kb, if memory serves me right. As I said, use a file.

Comment: @ Maxim, it says in the man pages you sent that the maximum pipe size can be changed in /proc/sys/... does it really apply?

Comment: @user1432779 Depends on the kernel version.

Comment: 3.2.0-29-generic the server is ubuntu 12.04 64

Comment: @user1432779 I am not familiar with that version and distro.